# How can i write XML into Silverlight by Master Details Meta Data Object

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-toolkit

I am being astonished that there is no new post about silverliht.It will be very harmful to our company because my company still now in silverlight and they have not finished their ERP and they have no chance to change silverlight to other technology at this moment.that for causes we have to study in silverlight.Ok.
My questions:
I want to convert XML by my master details object. suppose i have a master like table_Personal and details table JOB INFO.so how can i write into single xml file at a time.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this, but you say you have two tables. You can setup a relationship between these Objects in a DataSet, and then you can easily generate XML from this. DataSet.WriteXML doesn't seem to exist in Silverlight, but the post [Convert Dataset to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384014/convert-dataset-to-xml) is a post on how to implement this.

To find the DataSet in Silverlight you should put using System.Data; in top of the .cs file. Example of DataSet code:

```
System.Data.DataSet myDataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
myDataSet.Tables.Add(...);
myDataSet.Tables.Add(...);
myDataSet.Relations.Add(new System.Data.DataRelation(....));
```

Comment: You have not DataSet Class into Silverlight.Have you ever done in silverlight project. if yes please send me example.

Comment: It is found in System.Data and I have used it in Silverlight 5 several times. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: There is no direct way to do this and the few ways that are there are not recommended as a good practice. Best option would be to go for a third party control which can function similar to a DataSet. you can see the big boss post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315131/unable-to-set-a-reference-to-system-data-dll-in-a-silverlight-client-project

Comment: I agree With that post on the statement that you should not use DataSets to do serious data handling in Silverlight. For that I would recommend Entity Framework. But, the System.Data is there, and DataSet is there, and it can be useful in some settings. I use EF for all data handling, but I have used DataTable to build data for a grid With dynaimic number of columns, so there are some uses for it. But Your question was not about what is the best way to handle data in Silverlight. You asked how to get Your two datatables into XML, and for that I hope my answer will work.